# Where in the code is recently viewed products added to the database table?

Tags: magento-enterprise

I have a site that has recently viewed products not working for whatever reason.  It could very much be because someone stripped out some part of the code somewhere that handles this functionality.

I was able to find the database table report_viewed_product_index which is defined as:

```
    <models>
        <reports>
            <class>Mage_Reports_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>reports_resource</resourceModel>
        </reports>
        <reports_resource>
            <class>Mage_Reports_Model_Resource</class>
            <deprecatedNode>reports_mysql4</deprecatedNode>
            <entities>
                <event>
                    <table>report_event</table>
                </event>
                <event_type>
                    <table>report_event_types</table>
                </event_type>
                <compared_product_index>
                    <table>report_compared_product_index</table>
                </compared_product_index>
                <viewed_product_index>
                    <table>report_viewed_product_index</table>
                </viewed_product_index>
                <viewed_aggregated_daily>
                    <table>report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily</table>
                </viewed_aggregated_daily>
                <viewed_aggregated_monthly>
                    <table>report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly</table>
                </viewed_aggregated_monthly>
                <viewed_aggregated_yearly>
                    <table>report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly</table>
                </viewed_aggregated_yearly>
            </entities>
        </reports_resource>
    </models>
```

So I searched the code base for `reports/viewed_product_index` to see if I can find a `->save()` going on somewhere but that didn't seem to lead me any where.

Any thoughts on how to go about finding where this happens?

Answer (score 1):

You assume that someone had stripped out the code which calling this.

- This might be a modification in the core (`app/code/core`) - so I suggest to diff your code against the original Magento code
- Also the code could be removed by a class overwrite in an extension: Disable all extensions and see if the problem still persists. Then enable them step by step.

Comment: This is helpful, but it turns out my mistake was that the recently added product excludes the current product from its list.  Because I didnt realize this, I thought it was broken and not working. :-x

Answer (score 0):

I got lucky and found the event in the config.xml which led me to this method in `Reports/Model/Event/Observer.php`

```
public function catalogProductView(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $productId = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId();

    Mage::getModel('reports/product_index_viewed')
        ->setProductId($productId)
        ->save()
        ->calculate();

    return $this->_event(Mage_Reports_Model_Event::EVENT_PRODUCT_VIEW, $productId);
}
```

Now to figure out why that isnt being called!